# React Native ListView scroll to unrendered item

Tags: react-native

I'm using a ListView in React Native that is rendered with about 500 items from an api request. I can't work out if there's a way to scroll to say the 450th item if it hasn't been rendered yet.

my ListView is

```
 <ListView
                ref={(ref) => this.listView = ref}
                style={{ flex: 1 }}
                dataSource={StockTakeStore.dataSource}
                renderRow={(item) => this.renderRow(item)}
                enableEmptySections={true}
            />
```

The listview intially renders a handful of items then as you scroll it renders more items until all items have been rendered. Once this has happened it is possible to use

```
this.listView.getScrollResponder().scrollTo({ y: indexToScrollTo });
```

but if you try using this before manually scrolling down the list then it just scrolls to the bottom of the rendered children and not to the indexToScrollTo value. This is all for Android, i'm guessing iOS has the same behaviour